# Could Android Jetpack Navigation components handle back action in fragment?

Tags: android, android-jetpack

I'm using Android Navigation components in my project. I'd like to handle "Back" action in my main fragment (such as `Activity#onBackPressed`), and do something or block this action.
Is Navigation provides any similar APIs? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can oveeride back button using this callback

```
class MyFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        // This callback will only be called when MyFragment is at least Started.
        val callback = requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this) {
            // Handle the back button event
        }

        // The callback can be enabled or disabled here or in the lambda
        requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(viewLifecycleOwner, callback)
    }
    ...
}
```

For more information [click here](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-custom-back)

Answer (score 0):

Inside a fragment, try this:

```
NavHostFragment.findNavController(this).navigateUp()
```

Comment: Sorry, I mean to detect or prevent backing up, not back up manually.